# byte-wise identical Vs. equivalent content

Tags: java, duplicates, html

If we have two web pages, say, one at `www.example.com/a` and other at `www.anotherExample.com/b`, what the difference is between byte-wise identical content of these two page and equivalent content of these two pages? Considering Java, is there any tool or library to investigates either cases?

**EDIT**

To narrow down the scope of my question, I refer readers of this question to the following [article](http://www8.org/w8-papers/4c-server/mirror/mirror.html) at section 2.

Comment: This question is way to vague. What does "equivalent content" even mean? Certainly things like rearranging tags in the `<head>` of a web page can often be done without changing the way the page displays or reacts to events, but is that "equivalent"? Perhaps not, if it results in, say, style sheet files being loaded in a different order. At the other extreme, two pages may look and be organized completely differently, but be "equivalent" in logical content as far as a human looking at them is concerned.

Comment: @TedHopp `What does "equivalent content" even mean?`That is the whole point of my question. if It will help to make it more clear, i refer you to [this article](http://www8.org/w8-papers/4c-server/mirror/mirror.html) where at section 2 it raises 
byte-wise identical Vs. equivalent content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, section 2 of that article explains what *the authors* mean by equivalent content:

> ... pages often change at the byte level (e.g., by the addition of blank lines, by HTML reformatting, etc) without any change of content. Hence we say that two pages are *content equivalent* if they have identical content after such normalizations.

There is no standard meaning to the phrase; it's meaning in the context of that article is simply what they say it means.

I'm not aware of any Java tools or libraries that implement that definition specifically. However, I would interpret it to mean that two pages are content equivalent if they generate the same DOM.<sup>1</sup> So any tool that builds a DOM from a web page can be used to test content equivalence in the sense of that article.

EXAMPLE:

`original.html`:

```
<html>
<head><title>A page</title></head>
<body><h1>A page header</h1></body>
</html>
```

`content-equivalent.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>A page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>A page header</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The files `original.html` and `content-equivalent.html` are **not** byte-wise equal, but they are content equivalent.

1<sub>Note that this is a very strict interpretation. Even changes like reordering `<link>` and other meta-data elements would render two pages not content equivalent. That may or may not be what the authors intended. You'd have to ask them. But the language of the article suggests to me that is exactly what they intended.</sub>

Comment: That is just for byte-wise identical. If you look closely, there is a difference between byte-wise identical and content equivalent which I am still not sure what it is.

Comment: @lonesome - Well, _byte-wise_ is just what it sounds like: the two files are byte-for-byte identical. `diff` (or `fc`, if you're on Windows) shows no differences, even when white space is not ignored. If you add blank lines (that HTML would ignore), split an HTML tag over multiple lines, or reorder the attributes of a tag (among other possible changes) the files are no longer byte-wise identical, but they are still _content equivalent_.

Comment: So DOM is for content equivalent? But how to get the answer for content identical?

Comment: @lonesome - Please go read the paper more carefully, because it answers all this. It says "two pages are _content identical_ if they are byte-wise equal."

Comment: @lonesome - I added a trivial example that illustrates the difference between byte-wise equal (synonymous with content identical) and content equivalent.

Comment: @TedHopp my whole issue was the definition of byte-wise! I could not get what does it mean if they say two pages are byte-wise identical but surely I know what does it mean if two files are byte-wise identical. Maybe there was a misunderstanding.